# How to restructure a git repository into branches

Tags: git, refactoring, git-subtree, git-filter-branch

I have a git repository with a structure like this:

```
.git\
AB1\
AB2\
CD1\
EF1\
EF2\
```

and want to remodel it so that it is contained in three branches:

branchA with folders `AB1\ and AB2\`, branchB with the folder `CD1\` and branchC with folders `EF1\ and EF2\`. So that each branch contains only the folders of this branch but if I merge them back together no folder gets deleted. The history of each folder should be accessible separately and not intermingled like in the original repo. Yet they share a common ancestor as they are the same content in different programming languages.

Finally the history should look like this:

```
O--A------B--C   <-- branchA
    \
     D--E--F     <-- branchB
         \
          G-H    <-- branchC
```

I tried using the **subtree split** and the **filter-branch** methods, but they are either not re-mergeable or destroy the history of folders completely.

Is there any possibility to do this or at least a tool for restructuring git history?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't branch and delete the folders which don't belong in that branch?  This shouldn't affect the history of the branches which are retained, AFAIK.

Comment: I would like to have a folder specific history. That was not clear in the question.

Comment: Maybe tell us more about how you want the history to look like.  Do these three branches have _anything_ in common?  If not, then maybe you really want three separate repos.

Comment: Yes, they do have a common ancestor. They originate in the same code but have been transferred to different programming languages. And one of those branches would contain files for data preprocessing.